# Конфликт виртуальных машин

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtualbox

Пользуюсь win7. VirtualBox перестал видеть виртуализацию (она точно включена в настройках биоса) после установки и последующего удаления ScummVM.

Выплёвывает вот такую ошибку:

Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины Xubuntu.

The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: ConsoleWrap
Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Грешу на изменение каких-то настроек виртуализации виртуалкой ScummVM потому что до ее установки все работало без нареканий.

Есть ли способ вернуть настройки виртуализации "по умолчанию"?

Comment: Ну а строку `VT-x is disabled in the BIOS` гуглить не пробовал?

Comment: Конечно пробовал, проверил что виртуализация включена в Биосе а VT-x под семерку нет просто программно

Comment: Чё за мать\проц?

Comment: Модель ноута: asus N53S. Проц: intel i5-2410m. Мать: N53S

Comment: Хм, да, у проца есть поддержка vt-x. Ну ок. А в реестре никаких следов от скуммвм не осталось?

Comment: В реестре много следов от скуммвм. Почистить? Есть для этого какая-то утилита или надо вручную?

Comment: Реестр от любых следов скуммвм отчистил. Виртуалбокс все равно не запускается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56823151/5430535 ?

Comment: Статья супер. Спасибо. А это вообще безопасно выключать Virtualization Based Security?

Comment: Почитай сколько дырок находят в UEFI и прочих "защитных" штуках, которые официально призываны только для обеспечения безопаснти.